# Calculate unit normal vector for $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

They give me $S^1$ and this two parametrization of it:

- $X_1(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$
- $X_2(t) = (\sin t, \cos t)$

And they ask me to calculate for each parametrization one unit normal vector with differential forms.

So the thing I tried is:

1. Calculate $DX_1(t)= (-\sin t, \cos t)^t$;
2. Calculate $D_1 = \sqrt{\det(DX_1(t)^tDX_2(t)}$ that in this case $D = 1$;
3. Knowing that the unit normal vector is like $\mathbb{N}_1 = (N_1, N_2)$ we calculate $N_1$ and $N_2$;
4. $N_j=\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{D_1} \cdot \det\left[\frac{dX_~j}{dt}\right]$ (we apply det to the Jacobian matrix but without the line $j$)  and I have that $N_1 = \cos t = x$ and $N_2 = \sin t = y$;
5. And finally my unit normal vector $\mathbb{N_1} = (x, y)^t$;
6. By the same form I have that $\mathbb{N_2} = (-y, -x)^t$.

I don't know if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $X_1$, since $|X_1|=1$ then $X_1\cdot X_1=1$. Now differentiation and applying the product's rule you will have
$$0=\frac{d}{dt}(X_1\cdot X_1)=2X_1\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(X_1)$$
So $X'_1\cdot X_1=0$ and hence $X'_1$ is perpendicular to $X_1$.
Similarly for $X''_1$ which is $$X''_1=(-\sin t,-\cos t)^{\top},$$
and this is perpendicular to the tangent $X'_1$ and collinear to the position $X_1$.